# how to load nextage urdf in rviz

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I have been experimenting with URDF files and would like to load the Nextage urdf file.

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=`rospack find nextage_description\`/urdf/NextageOpen.urdf gui:=True
```

will launch rviz and I can see a white shape but as the panel on the left shows, there are many errors (see images above). Checking out the latest https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/tree/indigo-devel/nextage_description/urdf and visualizing this did not help either; same problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285172/how-to-load-nextage-urdf-in-rviz/) by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-12**:
Did you try setting a new fixed frame? Rviz is telling you that the one that you have selected does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using `WAIST` as the `Fixed Frame`. This is what's done in [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage/Tutorials/Changing%20Nextage%20Grippers%20in%20Robot%20Model#Create_URDF_model)

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage/Tutorials/Changing%20Nextage%20Grippers%20in%20Robot%20Model?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nxo_urdf_tutorial_rviz.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage/Tutorials/Changing%20Nextage%20Grippers%20in%20Robot%20Model?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nxo_urdf_tutorial_rviz.png)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2